How does the 'Curious' badge work?
I am attempting to get the 'Curious' badge. The last time I checked (not today) it was at 3/5, then dropped to 2/5. I was looking at my questions and found that one of them with a vote (upvote to be more specific) of '2' was marked as closed. Does having a closed question despite having a more than 0 upvotes cause it to drop?

Also, I got 5/5 for this badge and it still shows as incomplete, what do i do


In order to qualify for any of these badges, you must have a "positive
question record", which means you don't have too many Closed,
Negative, or Deleted questions overall.
The formula is
(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5. Questions that qualify as Negative and Closed and Deleted count three times in this
calculation. If you don't, you won't earn any of these badges.

What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?
I haven't done the math but closed questions and negative questions count against you. Use the equation to make sure you get the badge.
